# Moving Object along a path: How to call actionPerformed only after previous actionPerformed has finished?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a question about Swing Timer, specifically how to call `actionPerformed` a number of times and waiting for the last `actionPerformed` to finish before executing it again. I know other people have asked this before, but none of the solutions I found work for my program.

Heres what I have:
I am trying to use Square objects (Rectangles) along a path from one position to another. The path is given as an array of square objects (path is discovered using A*, all the squares in the path are added to an `ArrayList`). The `actionPerformed` method moves the square from its current x, y position to the next, and next is as I mentioned the next square in the path. So for example:

Start (the moving square) is at x 200, y 50
End (the target square) is at x 300, y 150
The squares in the path to this position are (in x, y position):
(250, 50), (300, 50), (300, 100), (300, 150)

[image]

But instead of moving one square at a time, the moving square will move as seen below: (taking a shortcut).

[image]

I believe the reason is that the timer is not waiting for `actionPerformed` to finish, so before the square even started moving, the listener has already received the last square (300, 150) as the target, and then the moving square moves there directly..

Here's some of my code:

MovementListener (holds actionPerformed)

```
public MovementListener(Canvas canvas){
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

public void setSquares(Square moving, Square target){
    this.moving = moving;
    this.target = target;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // I tried adding a boolean here, to indicate if the action is finished or not, what I tried was:
    // setRunning(true); (set to false below, see at the end of this method)
    if (this.moving.getX() < this.target.getX()){
        moving.setLocation((int)(moving.getX() + 10), (int)(moving.getY()));
        this.canvas.repaint();
    } 

    if (this.moving.getY() < this.target.getY()){
        moving.setLocation((int)(moving.getX()), (int)(moving.getY() + 10));
        this.canvas.repaint();
    }
    // setRunning(false);
}
```

Here's the class that holds the listener and timer:

```
public Canvas(){
    // setup ActionListener
    listener = new MovementListener(this);
    timer = new Timer(100, listener);
}


public void startTimer(Square moving, Square target){ 
    // I tried using the isRunning variable here, so that the next actionPerformed doesn't get called unless listener is ready
    if (listener.isReady()){
        listener.setSquares(moving, target);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

And here's the code where the moving action starts (the Square `moving` is defined above). Also, the backwards for-loop is correct, the path `ArrayList` is in reverse order (last square at position 0, beginning of path at the end of the list):

```
for (int i = controller.getPath().size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
     Square target = controller.getPath().get(i);
     canvas.startTimer(moving, target);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been trying to figure this out for hours now.. 
Thanks :)

EDIT: 
Okay I got it to work doing it the way camickr described below:

the new `actionPerformed`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Square current = controller.getPath().get(0);
    if (this.moving.getX() < current.getX()){
        moving.setLocation((int)(moving.getX() + 10), (int)(moving.getY()));
        this.canvas.repaint();
    } 

    if (this.moving.getY() < current.getY()){
        moving.setLocation((int)(moving.getX()), (int)(moving.getY() + 10));
        this.canvas.repaint();
    } else {
        controller.getPath().remove(current);
    }

    if (controller.getPath().isEmpty()){
        canvas.getTimer().stop();
    }
}
```

This is now working!

Comment: Learning to use the Debugger and step through your code is worth it's time in gold...

Comment: I know how to debug, thanks for the helpful comment.

Comment: `I know how to debug,` - so where is you debug code that shows, the x/y location you calculate every time the Timer fires? We don't have access to your data. We can't tell you what is wrong. Also, you should just calculate the x/y variables separate and then do a single setLocation(x, y).

Comment: Uhm... "We can't tell you what is wrong".. you already did!

Comment: Well - for what it's worth...I appreciate you not responding with a hostile manner and escalating a simple comment, @kattapillar

Comment: I find the stackoverflow community extremely helpful. I spend lots of time here reading posts and usually find an answer without posting a new question. This platform is meant to help people. I follow the rules here, posting in a certain style and I try to explain what my issue is the best I can. I write down what I've tried. I don't know why I'm getting these weird comment from you guys. You don't HAVE to answer any questions here, you know? If you find my question stupid, just move on and respond to someone else's question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = controller.getPath().size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
     Square target = controller.getPath().get(i);
     canvas.startTimer(moving, target);
}
```

In your code above you iterate through the loop setting the Square position. The square position is set to the end before the Timer even has a chance to fire, so you only ever see the square painted in the last position.

When you use a Timer you don't need to use a loop. The Timer replaces the loop. You simply start the Timer. Then when the Timer fires you do something.

So, your logic would be something like:

1. Add the Square objects to the ArrayList
2. Start the Timer
3. When the ActionListener is invoked you a) get the first Square from the ArrayList b) move the object to the square c) remove the Square from the ArrayList
4. When the ArrayList is empty you stop the Timer.

Comment: I tried that (see edit above), but I guess I'm still getting something wrong.. Help?

Comment: Nvm, I got it. Had to use the controller.getPath() directly instewad of passing a new path ArrayList!